# Marking a particular event in the past candlestick and using that reference to mark for the next candles

Tags: pine-script

Description of the problem:
I want to start marking candles say after a particular date(user input).
my Marking criteria is to mark fractal high first and then mark fractal low and the process repeats itself. mark fractal low then look for fractal high and then look for fractal low and so on..
bar_index will give me the candle location of the first marking. Then how should i write the code so that all the markings are done as described abvoe.

Marking condition are as follow:
Fractal high condition=1. Marking should begin after fractal low has occurred.
2. mark the candle as fractal low when any next two candles close and high are above the reference candle.

vice versa for fractal low.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any hints guys??

Comment: Can you specify the question? the title and q's body are two different questions ) Include the pine snippet or screenshot with marks.